# Replace all characters between two characters in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string

I'm trying to replace all characters between two characters.

This is gonna be my input string:

```
P<HRVSPECIMEN<<SPECIMENC<<<<<<<K<K<K<K<KKKKKK\n10070070071HRVB212258F1407019<<<<<c<c<<<<<<06
```

And I am trying to get this output:

```
P<HRVSPECIMEN<<SPECIMENC<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<\n10070070071HRVB212258F1407019<<<<<<<<<<<<<<06
```

Comment: `(?:^|(?<=<))K+(?=<|$)` assuming `\n` is not a literal character.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but this doesn't remove the K's before `\n`

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't know if `\n` is a literal character? Is it literal, or the  newline character?

Comment: hey sorry for not mentioning it above, it is a newline character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should give you the results you want. It looks for a `K` or `c` that is preceded by a `K`, `c` or `<` and followed by a `K`, `c` or `<` or the end of line:

```
(?<=[Kc<])[Kc](?=[Kc<]|$)
```

You can use this with the `re.MULTILINE` flag to `re.sub`:

```
import re
s = '''P<HRVSPECIMEN<<SPECIMENC<<<<<<<K<K<K<K<KKKKKK
10070070071HRVB212258F1407019<<<<<c<c<<<<<<06'''
s = re.sub(r'(?<=[Kc<])[Kc](?=[Kc<]|$)', '<', s, 0, re.MULTILINE)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
P<HRVSPECIMEN<<SPECIMENC<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
10070070071HRVB212258F1407019<<<<<<<<<<<<<<06
```

If the `\n` in your string is a literal `\n` rather than a newline, just replace `$` in the regex with `\\n`:

```
s = r'P<HRVSPECIMEN<<SPECIMENC<<<<<<<K<K<K<K<KKKKKK\n10070070071HRVB212258F1407019<<<<<c<c<<<<<<06'
s = re.sub(r'(?<=[Kc<])[Kc](?=[Kc<]|\\n)', '<', s, 0)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
P<HRVSPECIMEN<<SPECIMENC<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<\n10070070071HRVB212258F1407019<<<<<<<<<<<<<<06
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/HLL84683)